# Missing text file line breaks when opened in an Android app

Tags: android, eclipse, stringbuffer, datainputstream

I have a simple program using ScrollView and TextView that displays a long text file, but it seems to delete the line breaks in it. Example, if the text file actually has

```
Bunnies are mean.
But it's okay.
Because they're fluffy.
```

it is displayed as

```
Bunnies are mean. But it's okay. Because they're fluffy.
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.textBunny);
DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(stream);
String line=null;

StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();

    try {
        while((line=d.readLine())!=null){
        buffer.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    txt.setText(buffer.toString());
```

Help, anyone? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
buffer.append(line).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```